# Find and highlight a unit separator character 0x1f in VIM

Tags: vim

The title says it all, how you can highlight all the hidden 0x1f(31) chars using vim? I tried :set list on its own as well as with

```
:set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
:set list
```

but no luck

Comment: In what sense are these characters hidden?  Maybe `:verbose set cole? cocu?` will shed some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:match`:

```
:match Search /\%x1f/
```

See the following for more information:

```
:h :match
:h /\%x
```

Comment: either your command doesn't work or I paste my text wrongly into vim or something else is cheating on me ;) but this doesn't work

Comment: I have tested it out and it works correctly. Make sure you have a 0x1f character. Do this by typing `i<c-r>=nr2char(31)<cr><esc>`

Comment: ok, I guess the software from which I copy it just removes that character

Comment: This command does not work for me either.  Java spits out the error stating this character is in this file, but this command returns nothing.

Comment: This is a match, it will only highlight it. Can you search via `/\%x1f/`? You can also verify the character with `ga` to see the details about a character under your cursor